# Ionic link without back button

Tags: ionic-framework

in my Ionic app - how can I add links to other states that would not add an entry into the navigation stack.

I need to add links to  that would move user to another state/view. And in some cases (not always) I don't want the 'back' button to appear in the nav, allowing user to return to the previous page. Is this achievable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use [$ionicHistory](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/).

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
            disableBack: true
        });
```